# Query Count Google Sheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Per category (example engineering) I need to perform 4 queries where the output of each query matches a number of persons.

3 of my queries worked ( for columns R - S - T), meaning the output is correct, yet the fourth (Column U) provides an inaccurate output and I cannot find the reason. The output is the same as the query of column R (1021) and should be 40. 
Some cells in columns (R-S-T-U) are blanks. 
Here is my function

```
=QUERY('JV Database'!A2:W6938,"select count(U)where D = 'Engineering' and R > date '2016-01-01' and R < date '2017-01-01'")
```

What am I missing? Current output is 1021 -- Expected output should be 40. 1021 is the output of the first query (which I also do not get why)

Comment: what exactly is the problem?  is the count to big, to small, not a number?  Not clear what your question is when you don't show output and expected output.

Comment: you are skipping the first day of 2016.. try R >= date '2016-01-01'

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, thks for your previous response

Comment: To debug this query, replace `select count(U)` with `select D, R, U`, so you will see exactly what rows are returned.

Comment: So I broke it down. It appears that when I do select count(U), the query counts all the empty cells. For example, the outcome is 9,000 whereas when I do a countA formula the result is 142. How can I exclude empty cells? I tried it: where U <> ''", yet I get 428 and not 142 (different result than the countA). I am counting dates, so perhaps a condition could be where U is a number. How can it be written in query format?

Answer (score 0):

The following formula excludes blank cells assuming you have a "/" in the non blank cells:
=QUERY('Jv Database'!A2:W9616,"select count(U) where U like '%/%' or U <>''") 
I finally get the output I want